# Wrong fan values on my laptop

Tags: thinkpad, fan

I have such problem:
Fan in laptop goes faster but in sensors and Psensor i see that fan speed goes down!
Fan works proper. More applications, more load causes faster fan work but indication says that fan go slower. Is it possible to solve it?

- Ubuntu 10.10, 12.04, 14.04
- Laptop: Thinkpad edge 14 intel (2010-2011 production)